# Retrieving timestamp from hbase row

Tags: java, hbase, flume

Using Hbase API (Get/Put) or HBQL API, is it possible to retrieve timestamp of a particular column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your client is configured and you have a table setup. Doing a get returns a [Result](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html)

```
Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("row_key"));
Result result_foo = table.get(get);
```

A Result is backed by a [KeyValue](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.html). KeyValues contain the timestamps. You can get either a list of KeyValues with list() or get an array with raw(). A KeyValue has a get timestamp method.

```
result_foo.raw()[0].getTimestamp()
```

Comment: does [0] indicate the first column in hbase? is there a way to the timestamp for a particular specified column name?

Comment: It has been long enough that I dont recall any details from those docs. Things have likely changed since then. Best thing is to fire up a console for you hbase setup and poke around.

Answer (score 1):

@codingFoo's answer assumes all timestamps are the same for all cells, but op's question was for a specific column. In that respect, similar to @peibin wang's answer, I would propose the following if you would like the last timestamp for your column:

Use the [getColumnLatestCell](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getColumnLatestCell-byte:A-byte:A-) method on your Result object, and then call the `getTimestamp` method like so:

```
Result res = ...
res.getColumnLatestCell(Bytes.toBytes("column_family"), Bytes.toBytes("column_qualifier")).getTimestamp();
```

If you want access to a specific timestamp you could use the [getColumnCells](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getColumnCells-byte:A-byte:A-) which returns all cells for a specified column, but then you will have to choose between the cells with a `get(int index)` and then call `getTimestamp()`

Answer (score 0):

```
result_foo.rawCells()(0).getTimestamp
```

is a good style

Comment: still need square braces around the index, e.g. `rawCells()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the follow will be better:

```
KeyValue kv = result.getColumnLatest(family, qualifier);
String status = Bytes.toString(kv.getValue());
Long timestamp = kv.getTimestamp();
```

since Result#getValue(family, qualifier) is implemented as

```
public byte[] getValue(byte[] family, byte[] qualifier) {
        KeyValue kv = this.getColumnLatest(family, qualifier);
        return kv == null ? null : kv.getValue();
    }
```