# Timestamp Based Scans in HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

For Example for hbase table 'test_table', Values inserted are:

```
Row1 - Val1 => t
Row1 - Val2 => t + 3
Row1 - Val3 => t + 5

Row2 - Val1 => t
Row2 - Val2 => t + 3
Row2 - Val3 => t + 5
```

on scan 'test_table' where version = t + 4 should return

```
Row1 - Val1 => t + 3
Row2 - Val2 => t + 3
```

How do i achieve time stamp based scans (Based on latest available value less than or equal to the timestamp) in HBase?

Comment: Do you want to make it in HBase shell or write a program for this? Take a look here on how to get the list of keys from the table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218085/how-to-list-all-row-keys-in-an-hbase-table, for each key you can issue `get` and get the timestamped entries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321741/retrieving-timestamp-from-hbase-row, then filter them based on your condition

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Consider this table:

```
hbase(main):009:0> create 't1', { NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 100 }
hbase(main):010:0> put 't1', 'key1', 'f1:a', 'value1'
hbase(main):011:0> put 't1', 'key1', 'f1:a', 'value2'
hbase(main):012:0> put 't1', 'key1', 'f1:a', 'value3'
hbase(main):013:0> put 't1', 'key2', 'f1:a', 'value4'
hbase(main):014:0> put 't1', 'key2', 'f1:a', 'value5'
hbase(main):015:0> put 't1', 'key1', 'f1:a', 'value6'
```

Here's its scan in shell with all the versions:

```
hbase(main):003:0> scan 't1', {VERSIONS => 100 }
ROW              COLUMN+CELL
 key1            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083314098, value=value6
 key1            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083294981, value=value3
 key1            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083293273, value=value2
 key1            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083291009, value=value1
 key2            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083305050, value=value5
 key2            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083299840, value=value4
```

Here's the scan limited to a specific timestamp, as you requested:

```
hbase(main):002:0> scan 't1', { TIMERANGE => [0, 1416083300000] }
ROW              COLUMN+CELL
 key1            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083294981, value=value3
 key2            column=f1:a, timestamp=1416083299840, value=value4
```

Here's the same in Java code:

```
package org.example.test;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        HTable table = new HTable(HBaseConfiguration.create(), "t1");
        Scan s = new Scan();
        s.setMaxVersions(1);
        s.setTimeRange (0L, 1416083300000L);
        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
        for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
            System.out.println(Bytes.toString(rr.getRow()) + " => " +
                    Bytes.toString(rr.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("f1"), Bytes.toBytes("a"))));
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that specifying the time range maximal value is [excluded](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setTimeRange(long,%20long)), which means that if you want to get the last value for all the keys with maximum timestamp T, you should specify upper bound of the range to T+1

Comment: in Scala, it does not work. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887556/hbase-scan-timerange-does-not-work-in-scala

Comment: It works fine.. We can further clean the output using shell or any other scripting language