# HBase Scan TimeRange Does not Work in Scala

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I write scala code to retrieve data based on its time range. Here're my code :

```
object Hbase_Scan_TimeRange {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //===Basic Hbase (Non Deprecated)===Start
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass)
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    BasicConfigurator.configure()
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
    val admin  = connection.getAdmin()
    //===Basic Hbase (Non Deprecated)===End

    val scan = new Scan()
    val _min = 1470387596203L
    val _max = 1470387596204L
    scan.setTimeRange(1470387596203L,1470387596204L)
    val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("tm_movie"))
    val scanner  = table.getScanner(scan)
    var result = scanner.next()
    println()
    while (result != null ) {
      //===start
      println(result)
    }
  }
}
```

However, **it does not work**.It still showing all data from `tm_movie`.

I am expecting it will same as below query in Hbase Shell :

```
scan 'tm_movie', { TIMERANGE => [1470387596203,1470387596204] }
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution by Fix its Iterator, Here're my code :

```
object Hbase_Scan_TimeRange {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //===Basic Hbase (Non Deprecated)===Start
    Logger.getLogger(this.getClass)
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    BasicConfigurator.configure()
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
    val admin  = connection.getAdmin()
    //===Basic Hbase (Non Deprecated)===End

    val scans = new Scan()
    scans.setMaxVersions(1)
    val _min = 1470387596203L
    val _max = 1470387596204L
    scans.setTimeRange(1470387596203L, 1470387596204L)

    val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("tm_movie"))
    val scanner  = table.getScanner(scans)
    val result = scanner.iterator()
    while(result.hasNext)
    {
        val data = result.next()
        val movieId = Bytes.toString(data.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),Bytes.toBytes("movieId")))
        val movieName = Bytes.toString(data.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),Bytes.toBytes("movieName")))
        val movieGenre = Bytes.toString(data.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("data"),Bytes.toBytes("movieGenre")))

        println()
        println("movieGenre::"+movieGenre)
        println("movieName::"+movieName)
        println("movieId::"+movieId)
    }

  }
}
```